# How to recover Sysman - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was running this set of commands in an attempt to fix an issue related to enterprise manager configuration:

```
SQL> drop role mgmt_user;
SQL> drop user sysman cascade;
SQL> drop user MGMT_VIEW cascade;
SQL> drop public synonym mgmt_target_blackouts;
SQL> drop public synonym setemviewusercontext;
```

however as you can see I dropped the SYSMAN user as well but i need to retrieve it. I have tried to search for it in the recyclebin but even that is not working .Please any ideas on how i can retrieve the SYSMAN user? Thanks

Comment: If your intent was to setup Enterprise Manager again you can run `emca -config dbcontrol db -repos create`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong, that would be something like this:

- locate `emreposcre.sql` file; should be in a directory whose name is like `D:\oracle11\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sysman\admin\emdrep\sql`
- run it as SYS
- you'll be asked to provide:

  - Oracle Home directory (you should know it), e.g. `d:\oracle11\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`
  - username (which is `sysman`, right?)
  - its password (whichever you want)
  - name of the temporary tablespace, e.g. `temp`
  - whether to echo SQL or not, e.g. `on`

Comment: Thank you for this solution! will try it now and give you feedback.

Comment: please how would I run the directory you provided as SYS. thank you!

Comment: You don't run the *directory*, but the EMREPOSCRE.SQL file which is located in that directory. Connected as SYS. Via SQL*Plus.